# How to ask if something is .present? in a view in Roda

Tags: roda

I am converting a Rails app to Roda. Here's a section of a partial.

```
# _banner.erb
<% if banner.present? %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

This returns the error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'present?' for []:Array`.

How can I get Roda to support something simple like checking if a variable is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All [`present?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) does is negate [`blank?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) which in turns looks like this. You could add this to your helper/service classes depending on your setup.

```
def present?
  !blank?
end

def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self
end
```